# 400 bad request invalid hostname only in android application

Tags: c#, java, android, asp.net-mvc

I have a asp.net mvc website deployed on a server, providing a few web interfaces to others. For example, getting the current user's information, my test C# console application looks like this:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
     try
     {
         var url = "http://api.fake.mysite.com/v1.0/user/current";
         var token = "e0034e1c082de62b74e361b15f9c6471";
         var encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token));
         client.Headers["Authorization"] = encoded;
         client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
         Console.WriteLine(client.DownloadString(url));
     }
     catch (WebException e)
     {
         //log the exception
     }
}
```

You can see the usage is pretty simple, just request the url via HTTP_GET, set the *Authorization* header to the encoded token. Actually it works fine in my machine. But some one else meets a strange issue when visiting this url in an android application, here is the java code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String token = "e0034e1c082de62b74e361b15f9c6471";
String url = "http://api.fake.mysite.com/v1.0/user/current";
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(token.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
httpGet.addHeader("Authorization", encoded);
httpGet.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

try {    
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    int responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    String response = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

then he got "400 bad request invalid host name" error. I've tried:

(1) make sure the variable "encoded" has the same value in C# and Java code.

(2) make sure the website's domain name is correctly set in server IIS

(3) all PCs/mobile phones can visit the test index page(http://api.fake.mysite.com)

(4) ping api.fake.mysite.com works fine

(5) if removing `httpGet.addHeader("Authorization", encoded);`, the Java program got a 401 Unauthorized result as expected(the server code under my control returns the result)

(6) some other applications using C# and PHP can use the web methods well, only android application can't(tested in two totally different android mobile phones, the android emulator got 400 invalid host name either)

(7) use IP instead of domain name http://xx.xx.xx.xx/v1.0/user/current, everything is the same. (xx.xx.xx.xx stands for the ip address)

(8) checked the IIS log, all requests to /v1.0/user/current returns 200/401/500, no 400 results.

(9) make sure the android application has internet permissions(actually we've added all permissions)

Does anyone know the reason or help to find the reason? Thank you very much, this issue is driving me crazy.

Comment: What are the server logs telling you?

Comment: @Orlymee: See my edit: item (8) in the list.

Comment: Check your `AndroidManifest` that u have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: Also in cases like this i use WireShark tool (http://www.wireshark.org/) for debugging. If u have access to server try to sniff transmitted packages. Or if server isn't available run your android app in the emulator on standalone PC and sniff requests.

Comment: @TheDimasig: Thanks for your reply. We've added all permissions. And also we capture data sent in the emulator. But it's really hard to understand.

Comment: Try to capture broken request from emulator and another one correct, and compare http headers and body. This will allow u to understand what's wrong

Comment: @DmitriyTarasov: I can capture requests using Fiddler in my machine to get information of the request from C# code. But I don't know how to capture the request from Android.

Comment: @DannyChen download and install http://www.wireshark.org/ Choose in wireshark network interface wich communicates with android emulator and filter required packets, for instance by IP. Short manual how to use wireshark here http://www.howtogeek.com/104278/how-to-use-wireshark-to-capture-filter-and-inspect-packets/

Comment: I've got the same problem but only on devices running Gingerbread. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Exception-al: Nope, I already left the company.

Answer (score 0):

Should be `httpGet.addHeader("Authorization", "basic " + encoded);` and `String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(token.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);`

Answer (score 0):

I  struggled the very same problem. I can send HTTP POST from Fiddler or any other tool to my asp.net web API in debug mode but I can not access from my android application.

1. I tried to be sure to connect from my computer browser to
   web  API interface.
2. I tried to be sure to connect from android emulator web
   browser(AEWB). And then I deployed my web api to IIS so I can get      certain address to access from AEWB.

I can accessed to this adres from my AEWB

```
http://10.0.0.2:8088/api/tran

http://10.0.0.2 -> this is your local host address seen from Android
8088  -> this is your port of web api hosted on IIS
/api  -> this is web api
/tran -> this is your controller
```

[image: I can get json values from my IIS adres with AEWB]

Comment: I've already left that company. But I remember at last we still didn't resolve this issue. The Android developer used another solution to avoid this but I don't know how. BTW you should not post "I have the same problem" as an answer.